# How to select all options of values in Gvismotionchart ( googlevis) in R studio?

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, googlevis

I am trying to build GoogleVis Motion map by using gvismotionchart in r. I have created a char using below code. I want to select all "id" in  chart  attached . How I can do that ?

Code :

```
M<-gvisMotionChart(NewData,idvar = "op_sys",timevar = "creation_time",xvar = "weeknum1",chartid = "chartID" )
plot(M)
```

[image]

Please anyone could help ?

Comment: If you click on Hyperlink, you can see the image Googlevis has produced !

Comment: Thanks David for improving question!